# 404 страница в помощи при переходе из уведомлений

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, уведомления

При нажатии на **+100** переходит по ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation, которая показывает 404 "Страница не найдена".

[image: Картинка нотификаций]

Ввиду скудности [помощи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/), в которой всего 2 страницы может стоит просто всегда перебрасывать на помощь? Или давайте переведем сами страницы, можно использовать сторонние сервисы для перевода типа https://www.transifex.com/ ?

Comment: Проверил, уже исправлено.